# Is there an orthogonal matrix that diagonalizes both $A$ and $B$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization, orthogonal-matrices

> Let $$A=\begin{bmatrix}2&-1\\-1&1\end{bmatrix} \quad\text{and}\quad B=\begin{bmatrix}-1&-1\\-1&1\end{bmatrix}.$$ Is there an orthogonal matrix $Q$ that satisfies $Q^tAQ, Q^tBQ\\$ are both diagonal?

I know since $A$ is a complete positive matrix then both $A$ and $B$ are simultaneously diagonalisable, but how I can define whether it's possible to diagnolize them with an orthogonal matrix?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If there were a matrix $S$ such that $D=S^{-1}AS$ and $E=S^{-1}BS$ were both diagonal, then since diagonal matrices commute we would have
$$ AB=(SDS^{-1})(SES^{-1})=SDES^{-1}=SEDS^{-1}=(SES^{-1})(SDS^{-1})=BA $$
But in this case $AB\neq BA$, so $A$ and $B$ aren't simultaneously diagonalizable, even without the restriction that $S$ be orthogonal.

Comment: Take the matrix P that in the first row you have (0,1) and in the second row (1,1), Then $P^tBP$ and $P^tAP$ are both diagonal..

Comment: Your matrix $P$ is not an orthogonal matrix.

Comment: But you said that A and B are not simultaneously diagonalizable even without the restriction that S be orthogonal, here P diagnolize both

Comment: I did. Notice the use of $S^{-1}$ in my proof. For an orthogonal matrix $Q^T=Q^{-1}$, but this is not the case for a non-orthogonal matrix.

Comment: Right! now that make sense. But saying that A and B aren't simultaneously diagonalizable is not completely true since simultaneously diagonalization is not only about orthogonal matrices, am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

If such a $Q$ exists, then $A^t (A-B) Q$ is also diagonal, but what is $A-B$?

Comment: Why is $A^t(A-B)Q$ must be diagonal?